# Custom buttons in XIB used as Custom UITableViewCell don't respond to taps (ios7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, ios7

So here I am upgrading a working ios6 app to ios7, and now I can't receive taps or other actions on custom buttons (or other subviews) inside my tableviewcells.

Edit:

My code:

Here is where I deploy my PlaceCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PlaceCell";

    PlaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlaceCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib lastObject];
        cell.reuseIdentifier = cellIdentifier;
    }
    [cell configureCellWithPlace: [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

And then it is a normal custom cell with buttons which are connected to some actions by the interface.
It works perfectly with iOS6, but it does nothing with iOS7.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please tell what you are doing in "configureCellWithPlace" method ?

Comment: I solved my problem with that line:
    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO];
Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Solved with:

```
[cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO];
```

Comment: It doesn't. Also how does that solve it? I mean your buttons are part of contentView. Disabling userInteraction in contentView will disable userInteraction on the bottom too.

Comment: This will only work for apps that have the older style of creating a custom UITableViewCell, where in the XIB, there is no ContentView.  That's why it works for some cases and not others.

Comment: This will work because the cell will no longer respond to the touch event.  However, if you want the button to do one thing and a touch elsewhere in the cell to do another, this is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

Put your button into cell's `contentView`.

Comment: You mean it's not that automatically?

Comment: not if you created the view with an older version of Xcode originally.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when your Cell's view in xib file is not a UITableViewCell, but only a UIView. Make sure that that the xib's top view is a UITableViewCell.

You can easily check it by looking into the first child of the main view inside the interface builder. If the first subview is not "Content View" then you should rebuild the cell with UITableViewCell on the top.

Also make sure that button is a subview of the "Content View".

Comment: The various other fixes didn't work for me, but this solved it. Thank you Maros.

Comment: I've created a new `xib` file where the root view is a `UITableViewCell`, then its subview is a `Content View`, then its subviews are a `UIButton` and a couple of `UILabel`... the problem reported in this post remains for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I had dragged a `UIView` into the xib to use as my `UITableViewCell`. Even though I changed the classname to a subclass of a `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder, the events on my buttons still didn't fire. Since it was originally a `UIView`, IB never knew about `contentView` and didn't add my controls to it.

Dragging a "real" `UITableViewCell` into the xib, changing its class to the one I wanted, and then rewiring up the `IBOutlets` fixed everything. Didn't need to mess with `delaysContentTouches` or other properties either.

Moral of the story: drag the right thing onto your xibs.

Comment: Xcode 6 automatically adds a view to the nib as UIView, so I just assumed I could select UITableView in the dropdown. So you need to delete the UIView it creates and drag on a UITableViewCell as suggested. Tricky!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that when you use interface builder to customize a cell subclass all the views added are added below the contentView. This is why setting userInteractionEnabled = NO on the content view works, because touch events are allow to pass through.

I used `po [view recursiveDescription]` with lldb to determine this.