# How in the earth [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]; solves this?

Tags: uibutton

I have the exact same problem

[Custom buttons in XIB used as Custom UITableViewCell don't respond to taps (ios7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781063/custom-buttons-in-xib-used-as-custom-uitableviewcell-dont-respond-to-taps-ios7?rq=1)

Basically buttons in UITableViewCell no longer works.

It used to work fine in IOS 6. Not anymore in IOS 7.

I saw 2 people with the same solution

```
[cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]
```

However, the solution doesn't make sense at all.

The buttons are obviously a subview of cell.contentView. If we set userinteractionenabled to no, it should disable user interaction to all the subviews of cell.contentView. So how the hell this work at all?

Actually what have changed between IOS 7 to IOS 6 so that this problem exist in the first place.

Note: It doesn't really solve my problem.

As I suspected, the buttons inside UITableViewCell is indeed a subview of contentView

```
2013-10-11 13:07:04.946 [15131:a0b] self: <BGCatalogTableCellForCatalog: 0x12e12d20; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 220); layer = <CALayer: 0x12e12c70>>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.947 [15131:a0b] self.contentView: <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12e12600; frame = (0 0; 320 220); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12e12440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12e125d0>>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.947 [15131:a0b] self.btnBrochureButton: <UIButton: 0x12e100b0; frame = (0 0; 160 219); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x12e102c0>>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.948 [15131:a0b] self.btnBrochureButton.superview: <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12e12600; frame = (0 0; 320 220); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12e12440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12e125d0>>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.948 [15131:a0b] self.btnBrochureButton.superview.superview: <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12e12920; frame = (0 0; 320 220); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12e12840>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12e128f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.949 [15131:a0b] self.btnBrochureButton.superview.superview.superview: <BGCatalogTableCellForCatalog: 0x12e12d20; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 220); layer = <CALayer: 0x12e12c70>>
2013-10-11 13:07:04.949 [15131:a0b] <UIButton: 0x12e100b0; frame = (0 0; 160 219); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x12e102c0>>
```

So both the btnBrochureButton.superview and self.contentView is 0x12e12600

Answer (score 2):

I got the problem fixed. Starting in IOS 7, contentView is not a direct subview of UITableViewCell. This causes complication.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I found that my issue was related to the issues described in the posts you referenced, but I also had one more piece of the puzzle.  The `contentView.userInterActionEnabled = NO` didn't work for me, for the same reason you described.

In my app, I'm dynamically resizing the table view cells, changing their heights at runtime based on the content in the cell.  This created a separate issue for me where the cell was being resized, **but the contentView, for some reason, was not being resized.**  So my button was visible, but was outside the bounds of the contentView and therefore not available to user interaction.

The way I finally discovered it was by setting the **background color of my contentView** to a different color, where I finally saw that it was too short.  I solved the issue by changing the height for the contentView after I calculated the total height for the parent cell.

I hope this can help you or at least give you something new to check for.