# TableView editing mode deletion button overlaps

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview

Currently I am working on an app where I have a `UITableViewController` and wan't to be able to delete the items. So I added the correct buttons and methods. However when I press the edit button the deletion icons appear over the my text.

With the default UITableViewCell this is not happening. Then the text moves so it clears free from the button. How could I achieve this in my own table view cell?

[image: Table editing error]

Comment: Are all the labels you are using in the cell's `contentView` or in it's `view`?  Views you add to UITableView should be added to it's `contentView` property.

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if you used the "swipe to delete"? I know it doesn't answer your question, just wondering...

Comment: Well, actually I want both. And to answer the question of Putz1103. I have created a xib with a view, set it's class to UITableViewCell and loaded that through "registerNib forCell".

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Putz1103 this happens when you place your views on the `view` instead of the `contentView`. The `contentView` is handled by iOS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With the answers provided here I continued my search. And this answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19248062/393548) is what I did wrong. I had a UIView (of which I changed it's class in the Interface Builder to a subclass of UITableViewCell.

But I had to drag out a UITableViewCell, and that one did have a contentView property.

Thanks for the responses.